# Change parent controller model through directive $watch using controllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm new to controllerAs syntax of angular and just trying to understand how it works with directive. I've created one directive for password validation. I want to make some flag true based on conditions and those will be used in parent template for displaying error messages. I'm not getting how can I achieve this!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/244/)

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="PersonCtrl as person">
        <input name="emailID" type="text" ng-model="person.first" >
        <input name="pass" type="password" ng-model="person.pass" password-validator>
        <p ng-show="person.showMsg">Password validation message here.</p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
myapp.directive('passwordValidator',function() {
        return {
        controller : PasswordCtrl,
      controllerAs : 'dvm',
      bindToController : true,
      require : ['ngModel','passwordValidator'],
      link : function(scope,ele,attrs,ctrls) {
        var person = ctrls[1];
        var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];

        scope.$watch(function() {
                    return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        },function(newVal) {
          if(newVal!='') {
            person.showMsg = true;
          } else {
            person.showMsg = false;
          }
          console.log(person.showMsg);
        });
      }
    }

    function PasswordCtrl() {

    }
});
```

> Specially I want to understand why and how below watch is working fine!

```
// Why this below is also working, can anyone explain what's going behind!! 
scope.$watch('person.pass',function(newVal) {
    console.log("Watch fires");
});
```

This is just for learning purpose so please explain how `controllerAs` and `bindToController` works!

Comment: what is your requirement? explanation or solution

Comment: Solution with detail explanation how exactly it works.

Comment: When using directives in angularjs (or when just using angularjs), its important to understand the digest lifecycle which basically is the dirty checking on changes between the scope model and view. It's the core function which makes our lifes much easier. Here's the best article I've read on that topic https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: The fiddle is working fine! with some condition changes for msg true and false .So whats your issue here ?

Comment: Can you give me working fiddle link? what have you changed?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FMThNTlmNtVQcznnUwUV?p=preview here you go,I made changes that if user types password then show msg if its blank remove msg

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem and why it's not populating firstname and password on load?

Comment: try commenting the controllerAs : 'person', in directive it populates but the watcher stops working because it will now can table to find out the person alias scope objects

Comment: @Angular_10 Read my question, I'm trying to understand controllerAs and you're saying to comment it out. I don't need solution or work around. :)

Comment: [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/245/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was not part of your question, I will get to it, but using directive 'ng-controller' is an anti-pattern. If if are interested why I can explain in a separate post but in short it makes code much harder to follow.

Now, to get to the heart of your question.

From reading the Angular documentation for `bindToController` it would appear that if you are not also creating an isolated scope, i.e. `scope: true` or `scope: {}` it does not do anything.

Personally I have never used it before and does not seem particularly useful.

Using ng-controller is in essence adding a property to the current scope with that controller object.

So:

```
<fieldset ng-controller="PersonCtrl as person">
```

Is effectively saying, (in a contrived way):

```
$scope.person = new PersonCtrl();
```

Your directive `passwordValidator` which is using the `controllerAs` syntax within it is basically doing:

```
$scope.dvm= new PasswordCtrl();
```

In this case you effectively have a scope object that looks like:

```
$scope = {
    person = new PersonCtrl(),
    dvm: new PasswordCtrl()
}
```

Your `person` controller and `dvm` controller are sibling objects.
Within your `passwordValidator` directive you are requiring in its controller, which is the `dvm` object. Using that `dvm` object are you setting `person.showMsg` which is the same as doing:

```
$scope.dvm.person.showMsg = <value>
```

The `dvm` object does not have a way to access the `person` object, as they are siblings, on the $scope. So you need to use the $scope itself to access the person object. You would need to do:

```
$scope.person.showMsg = <value>
```

Although this assumes that `person` exists on the scope, which is a dangerous assumption.

Answer (score 1):

your example is kinda messy but ill try to answer your questions.

```
// Why this below is also working, can anyone explain what's going behind!! 
scope.$watch('person.pass',function(newVal) {
    console.log("Watch fires");
});
```

this works because your directive is using SAME scope and variables on it as its parent controller.

```
this.checkDirCtrl = function() {
    console.log($scope.dvm);
}
```

`this` is undefined because you are using controllerAs on SAME scope so new variable called `dvm` is not created and all your `dvm` controller variables are initialized on parent scope.

That means that you dont need to 'inject' person controller into directive because you already have controller instance on directive scope. So just set your variable 'showMsg' like this and it will work like a magic!

```
      if(newVal!='') {
        scope.person.showMsg = true;
      } else {
        scope.person.showMsg = false;
      }
      console.log(scope.person.showMsg);
```

I made a fiddle for you: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1r7q3vu/)